# Find the Last Occurrence of a search string And Print the Line next line in Ksh

Tags: regex, awk, grep, ksh

How can we Find the last occurrence a search string (Regex) and then print the next line following it? Assume a Textfile which has Data as below

```
1 absc
1 sandka
file hjk
2 asdaps
2 amsdapm
file abc
```

So, from this file, I have to grep or awk the last occurrence of the 2 and print the line that follows it.

Comment: Now that I see you back in the track, did this work to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` is always handy for these cases:

```
$ awk '/2/ {p=1; next} p{a=$0; p=0} END{print a}' file
file abc
```

#### Explanation

- `/2/ {p=1; next}` when `2` appears in the line, activate the `p` flag and skip the line.
- `p{a=$0; p=0}` when the `p` flag is active, store the line and unactivate `p`.
- `END{print a}` print the stored value, which happens to be the last one because `a` is always overwritten.

Comment: This will find and count `2`everywhere in the line.  If its just in the beginning you should  use `$1==2` or `/^2/` to prevent hits of `2` other location int the line.

Comment: Yes, it sounds logical, but the OP is just saying `i have to grep or awk the Last occurrence of the 2`. In case s/he updates with more specific indications I will update, probably (if you don't mind) using the `/^2/`.

Comment: I have no problem with that  :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`

- `grep -A 1 '^2`' option displays lines that match `2` at the beginning of the line **plus** one following line
- then use `tail -1` to print the final line:

> grep -A 1 '^2' yourfile | tail -1